# How to get the row id onClick in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a table populated with dynamic data. the last column has a button which when I click I would like to pass the row id to the JS function.
I need the id because I am doing a POST Ajax request and on success I want to take the response data and update the selected row with new data.

This is what I would do to insert a new row:

```
var rowNode = myTable.row.add([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).draw();
```

but what can I do to get the row ID and update it with the response data?

EDIT. Datatable:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Reg</th>  
                <th>Edit</th>                   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach (get_all_customers_list() as $user) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b> <?php echo $user["recipient_name"]; ?></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $user["registration_date"]; ?>
                        </td>                       
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" id="button_edit" onclick='edit_customer_request(<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>)' value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="edit_customer">Editt</button>                             
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example of your Data tables.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping there you go. I really dont know what else to add because this is not something like a bug which I cant figure out why code is behaving differently but its something that I dont even know how to handle.

Comment: Where is your new id appearing ? is it in a button ? To clarify you want to get the `id` of the row where you click at ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, I basically want the ID of the selected row (using the button, I dont click on row) and pass it to the function. I need the row ID so that I know which row to update later,

Comment: @AlwaysHelping any idea how to do it?

Comment: You have `edit` button in each row - right ? And when you click on edit button you want to get the `id` of that row and then update the same row with new data ? Am i correct - I am making sense - so i can provided a proper solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hope you like it here. Given that this is a client-side question providing actual HTML - harvested from the browser - can be very helpful in understanding and answering your question. No need to post server-side code if it does not clarify your question. **Otherwise we become the web server and we have to process the server-side code in order to address your question. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes that's correct.

Comment: @PeterKA what server-side code have I posted?

Comment: PHP is server-side and only need be posted if it clarifies the question.

Comment: @PeterKA it does clarify because there is a loop, so I am creating an Edit button foreach row. Without for loop that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>` this is where you store the id of each row ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I store the php values there and pass them to the JS function. I need the DataTable Row ID.

Comment: @B.S.  See the two solutions below to get the `rowID` of the `onclick` edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only wanted to get the `row id` of the `clicked` row edit button. You can simply use `table.row` function and pass the actual `tr` of the clicked button.

**Demo** (Showing the `actual id` (1, 2) which is stored as name)

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({})

//edit customer here
function edit_customer_request(_this) {
  //Getting the actual table ID
  var row = $(_this).parents('tr')[0];
  //Data table row id
  console.log(table.row(row).data()[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha512-BkpSL20WETFylMrcirBahHfSnY++H2O1W+UnEEO4yNIl+jI2+zowyoGJpbtk6bx97fBXf++WJHSSK2MV4ghPcg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" integrity="sha512-1k7mWiTNoyx2XtmI96o+hdjP8nn0f3Z2N4oF/9ZZRgijyV4omsKOXEnqL1gKQNPy2MTSP9rIEWGcH/CInulptA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<table id="myTable" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Reg</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tiger Blah</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="button_edit" onclick='edit_customer_request(this, 1)' value="1" name="edit_customer">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>tr>
    <tr>

      <td>2</td>
      <td>Blah Nixon</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="button_edit" onclick='edit_customer_request(this ,2)' value="2" name="edit_customer">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Demo** (Showing the actual index of table - Index start from 0 to depending on how many rows you have)

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({})

//edit customer here
function edit_customer_request(_this) {
  //get the closest of clicked edit button
  var tr = $(_this).closest("tr");
  //get the index of row
  var rowindex = tr.index();
  //Index of row
  console.log(rowindex)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha512-BkpSL20WETFylMrcirBahHfSnY++H2O1W+UnEEO4yNIl+jI2+zowyoGJpbtk6bx97fBXf++WJHSSK2MV4ghPcg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" integrity="sha512-1k7mWiTNoyx2XtmI96o+hdjP8nn0f3Z2N4oF/9ZZRgijyV4omsKOXEnqL1gKQNPy2MTSP9rIEWGcH/CInulptA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<table id="myTable" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Reg</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tiger Blah</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="button_edit" onclick='edit_customer_request(this, 1)' value="1" name="edit_customer">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>tr>
    <tr>

      <td>2</td>
      <td>Blah Nixon</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="button_edit" onclick='edit_customer_request(this ,2)' value="2" name="edit_customer">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, it works! How can I actually update that row?

Comment: @B.S. Glad to hear that. For update i would recemend on ajax success you need to remove that row and use `row.add` with that `index` - Also you need add the `edit button` dynamically as well.

Comment: @B.S. You can update the same as well. Yes! but then you will need to use jQuery `.append` or `.html` function. Ideally if a data is added dynamically then i will remove the row and add the new row with that data.

Comment: interesting! I didn't know I can use `.html` actually, which resets the element with the new data. However, the hardest part is to do .html() to that specific row using the `rowindex` that you posted earlier.

Comment: @B.S. Sure. You need to pass the index of that specific row like this with new data on ajax success. `table.row( rowindex ).data( newData ).draw();`

Comment: thanks but it fails with an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aoData' of undefined` . Btw why aren't you using `.html()` like you said?

Answer (score 1):

this is my simple answer:

```
var table = $('#table-values');

$('#table-values').on( 'click', 'tr', function(){
    var id = this.id;

    alert( 'Clicked row id '+id );
  });
```

Easy. :)